# R code for standardized coefficents and model effect size using nlme

Tags: effect-size, standardization, lme4-nlme

I have fit a longitudinal random effects model using `nlme` and I prefer `nlme` because I can get p-values. While working with a tutor, he ran the same model in `lme4` and obtained standardized coefficients and model effect size using the following codes.

The `lme4` model is:

```
model1<-lmer(logh_production ~ growth + p_will + subsidy + trt_grp + compliance + 
nn_cent + distance + city_net_exp + county_pop_avg_per_hh + county_vcncy + 
region_id + fiscal_year + (1|city_name), mydata)
```

For parameter effect size (standardized beta weights):
`fixef(model1) / sigma(model1)`

For effect size for whole model (variation in linear mixed effects models):
`1-var(residuals(model1))/(var(model.response(model.frame(model1))))`

What are the equivalent codes for using `nlme`?

Here is my complete `nlme` model:

```
test1 <- lme(logh_production ~ logh_demand + growth + p_will + logeh_supply + trt_grp   
+ compliance + logcity_area + nn_cent + distance + city_net_exp  + loglocal_assess + 
logcity_net_rev + county_pop_avg_per_hh + region_id + fiscal_year, data=ahpRAW, 
control=list(opt="optim"), method="ML", random= ~1 | city_name)
```

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example please?

Comment: Hi Ben, I revised the question to include examples of both the lme4 and nlme models. Just note, I'm not a stat or math person, just someone with "basic" R knowledge.

Comment: This is not a recommended practice even for ordinary linear models.  See elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Frank. What I'm trying to do is simply determine a) which is the most important variable of my statistically significant variables, and 2) how much power does my model contain. In this model, my variable of interest "compliance" is significant, but is it the most powerful variable? And more importantly, it this model useful, as only 5 variables are statistically significant?

Comment: It would be best to have a *reproducible* example -- that means you illustrate your problem with a data set we can get access to somehow (either something built in to an R package, or that you post somewhere on the web or (if not too big) paste into your question -- see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 for example ...